# Add node to end of linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I am working on a homework assignment involving linked lists. We have to implement a queue ADT, and the one method I am having trouble with is adding a node to the end of the list (the enqueue method). Here is my code:

public class Queue implements QueueInterface {

```
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int sz;

    public  Queue() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        sz = 0;
    }

    public void enqueue(T newEntry) {
        Node newElement = new Node(newEntry);
        newElement.next = null;
        tail.next = newElement;
        tail = newElement;
    }

    public T dequeue() {
        T result = null;
        if(head != null) {
            result = head.data;
            head = head.next;
            sz--;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public T getFront() {
        return head.data;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (head == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void clear() {
        while (!isEmpty()) {
            dequeue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Queue [head=" + head + ", sz=" + sz + "]";
    }

    public class Node {

        private Node next;
        private T data;

        public Node (T newData) {
            data = newData;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node [next=" + next + ", data=" + data + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

If anyone could help me out with this I would be really appreciative. Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: You have an `enqueue()` method. What's the problem with it, currently? And please do be more specific than "it's not working."

Comment: It's throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Xander - Right, because you aren't checking to see if it's the *first* thing you're adding. `tail` is null. You need to handle the case of adding the first item (and then also set `head` in that case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't handling the case where the list is empty. You're adding the *first* item, `tail` is `null` and you're getting the appropriate exception.

You need to check `tail` to see if it's `null` before attempting to use it, and act appropriately if that is the case. Don't forget to set `head` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line, next should already be null.

```
newElement.next = null;
```

You also forgot to incremement sz after your enqueue.

If you try and enqueue to an empty linked list what happens? You're going to have to deal with that case, it is why you are getting a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

```
public void enqueue(T newEntry) {
        Node newElement = new Node(newEntry);
        newElement.next = null;
        if(tail != null)
        {
        tail.next = newElement;
        tail = newElement;

        }else
        {
         head=tail=newElement;
        }
    }
```

Check if tail is null or not. if tail is null it means this is the first node. add this as first node. as add after the tail.

Answer (score 0):

Your enqueue method tries to set `tail.next` to `newElement`. What happens if the tail hasn't been initialized yet? You'll get a NullPointerException.